# Using math for listings

Tags: math-mode, sourcecode

I asked a question a while back on how to [typeset programs as beautiful math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631293/how-to-typeset-programs-as-beautiful-math). The suggestion I got was to use `listings`.  But this has been unsatisfactory.

Basically my 'programs' are in a gray area between programming and math.
They are ASCII text at some low level but the idea is that they should look like math equations:

- `=` signs properly lined up
- math fonts **and spacing**
- suitable replacement of ASCII by math artifacts as in Knuth-WEB

Here is the look with listings and math (`alignat`) interleaved, to show roughly what I would like to have.

[image: pdflatex output]

The latex source

```latex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\newcommand{\gufx}[1] {\scalemath{1.1}{\text{\,\guilsinglleft{#1}\guilsinglright}}\,\,}
\date{}
\title{A Title}

\begin{document}

\section{Examples}
\label{sec:org31daa8a}
Haskell eg1
\begin{HSK}
swaptree.(Leaf.x) = Leaf.x
swaptree.(Br.l.r) = Br.(swaptree.r).(swaptree.l)
\end{HSK}

Math eg1
{\small \begin{alignat*}{3}
&swaptree.(\textbf{Leaf}.x)&&= \textbf{Leaf}.x\\
&swaptree.(\textbf{Br}.l.r)&&= \textbf{Br}.(swaptree.r).(swaptree.l)
\end{alignat*}}

Haskell eg2
\begin{HSK}
c : Int -> Int -> Int
0     `c` (r+1) = 0
n     `c` 0     = 1
(n+1) `c` r     = n `c` r + n `c` (r-1)
\end{HSK}

Math eg 2
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&c &&: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\\
&0     &&\gufx{c} (r+1) &&= 0\\
&n     &&\gufx{c} 0     &&= 1\\
&(n+1) &&\gufx{c} r     &&= n \gufx{c} \! r  + n \gufx{c} \!(r-1)
\end{alignat*}

Haskell eg3
\begin{HSK}
ce : [t] -> Int -> [[t]]
[]     `cE` (r+1)= []
xs     `cE` 0    = [[]]
(x::xs)`cE` r    = xs `cE` r ++ [x::y| y <- xs `cE` (r-1)]
\end{HSK}

Math eg3
\begin{alignat*}{5}
&ce &&&&: [t] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow [[t]]\\
&[\,] &&\gufx{ce}(r\!+\!1)&&= [\,]\\
&xs &&\gufx{ce} 0 &&= [[\,]]\\
&(x::xs) &&\gufx{ce} r &&= xs \gufx{ce} r +\!\!\!\!\!+\,\, [x::y \mid y \in (xs \gufx{ce} \!(r\!-\!1))]\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The associated style file mystyle.sty

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[fleqn]{calculation}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[figurename=Code, font={small,it}, belowskip=-8pt, aboveskip=0pt]{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} 
%\usepackage{arevmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDA}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDA}{cmr}{m}{n}

\lstnewenvironment{HSK}
    {\lstset{language=Haskell,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        identifierstyle=\footnotesize\itshape,
        keywordstyle=\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries,
        aboveskip=5pt,belowskip=5pt,
        flexiblecolumns=false,
        morekeywords={ctype},
        frame=single,
        breaklines=true,
        basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
        frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR},
        literate={+}{{\texttt{+}}}1 {/}{{$/$}}1 {*}{{\texttt{*}}}1 {=}{{\texttt{=}}}1 {:}{{\texttt{:}}}1 {::}{{\texttt{::}}}2
        {>}{{$>$}}1 {<}{{$<$}}1 {\\}{{$\lambda$}}1
        {\\\\}{{\char`\\\char`\\}}1
        {->}{{$\rightarrow$}}4
        {>=}{{$\geq$}}2
        {<-}{{{\scriptsize$\in$}}}1
        {=}{{=}}3
        {.}{{\,.}}1
        %{Int}{{${\mathbf{Z}}$}}2
        %{...}{{$\ldots$}}2
        {,}{{\texttt{,}}}1
        {<=}{{$\leq$}}2 {=>}{{$\Rightarrow$}}2 
        %{\ .}{{$\circ$}}2 {\ .\ }{{$\circ$}}2
        {>>}{{>>}}2 {>>=}{{>>=}}2
        {|}{{$\mid$}}1
        {?}{{\textbf{?}}}1
    }}{}

\lstdefinestyle{HSKstyle}
{
  language=Haskell,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  identifierstyle=\footnotesize\itshape,
  keywordstyle=\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries,
  literate={+}{{\texttt{+}}}1 {/}{{$/$}}1 {*}{{\texttt{*}}}1 {=}{{\texttt{=}}}1 {:}{{\texttt{:}}}1 {::}{{\texttt{::}}}2  {->}{{$\rightarrow$}}4
}
\newcommand{\HSKinline}[1]{\lstinline[style=HSKstyle]{#1}}
```

As one can see the math hacks are quite horrible!
The holy grail is of course if I could just drop in the source code as in in a suitably tailored alignat (or whatever) mode. I am assuming this is quite hard!

But a few things would help:

1. Sed like replacements

   - -> to \rightarrow
   - Tree to $\mathbf{Tree}$
   - Int to $\mathbb{Z}$ etc
   - Better if all upcased names can be so handled but if thats harder just a list of
     mathbf names in some setup place
2. operator specs rather than `\,` `\!` hacks
3. `` `identifier` `` to `identifier` in guillemet with operator spacing
4. Newlines to be prepended by `\\`
5. Insert `&&` before `=` (but not before `==`)
6. To be able to restart `alignat`s aligning without a new `alignat`
   Just see example 3: The first line is **compelled** to be aligned along with the remaining 3. It should be independent.

---

PS Thanks to egreg for [the encouragement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146359/53864) to ask.

Please ignore the visible frames or lack thereof

Comment: Added the style file to hopefully make a MWE